# Etymology and Elizabethan English connotations of "sat at meat" (Mark 2:15, KJV)

Tags: etymology, translation, connotation, seventeenth-century-english

I came across a [King James (1611) translation of Mark 2:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%202%3A15-17&version=KJV):

> And it came to pass, that, as Jesus **sat at meat** in his house, many publicans and sinners sat also together with Jesus and his disciples: for there were many, and they followed him.

and was wondering why the Greek word κατακεῖσθαι (*katakeisthai*) was translated "sat at meat" instead of "reclined at table" as in modern literal translation such as [ESV (2001)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%202%3A15-17&version=ESV):

> And as he **reclined at table** in his house, many tax collectors and sinners were reclining with Jesus and his disciples, for there were many who followed him.

Even the [New King James version (1979)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%202%3A15-17&version=NKJV) translated it as "dining":

> Now it happened, as He **was dining** in *Levi’s* house, that many tax collectors and sinners also sat together with Jesus and His disciples; for there were many, and they followed Him.

**What is the etymology and the Elizabethan English connotations of "sat at meat"?**  Did "meat" imply that animal flesh was eaten, implying it's a major meal or a feast?  Did Shakespearean usage give us a clue what the KJV translators had in mind for the connotation assigned to the English word choice for κατακεῖσθαι in the [Greek text used for Mark 2:15 by KJV translators](https://www.textusreceptusbibles.com/Strongs/41002015/G2621)?

Comment: One has to be cautious about the interpretation of features of a translation.  The Greek word for 'meat' kreas (κρεας) does not occur.   κατακεισθαι (katakeisthai) is the word for 'reclining

Comment: How is this about English Language & Usage, more than Greek Translation?

Either way, go back 1,000 years and Danish clearly and Saxon prolly used 'meat' to mean 'food.'

More interestingly, why would you mind enough to Ask about that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Translation involves *first* understanding the word's meaning in source language and *then* finding the appropriate rendering in the target language.  Yes, the 1st task (involving Greek) doesn't belong to this Stack, but in wording the Q I have bracketed it to the 2nd task, and scope it to Elizabethan English & to the KJV translators's mind who did the rendering.  The accepted answer addresses both parts of the 2nd task well.  Now that the Q is in the hot network, I'm in anticipation for yet a better answer, at which I may then choose that answer to be accepted instead.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture and I hope the exercise cleared something up for you, anyway. Meanwhile, but in length, what you suppose TaliesinMerlin's Answer added to my earlier Comment?

Comment: FWIW, Tolkien uses the phrase "at meat" in this sense. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50381/116908

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin To answer "why would you mind enough to Ask about that", I took for granted the Greek language scholars' taking the word to mean "recline at table", leaving me to wonder what "sat at meat" has to do with that meaning in the mind of KJV translators.  As a newbie to Middle, not to mention Old English & the misty beginnings of the English language, I thought this stack is a good place to ask.  What TaliesinMerlin's answer adds to yours is the influence of earlier translation (including Vulgate) as possible factor, more details on the etymology and a brief intro to "false friends".

Comment: Take for granted what you like. Here, please Post the steps on the path from your source, even if the details bore most readers stiff!

Take for granted what Greek scholars mean in Greek fora, not here.

To switch from phrases under discussion to something unstated taking an unstated word to mean 'recline at table' can you explain first which word that was, or how it came to fit your idea? 

Without evidence, I suggest first that 'sat at…' is mostly irrelevant. Who doubts that? 

What if you drop all reference to Middle or Old or any misty beginnings of English?

Comment: Thanks Conrado and with more than due respect, you seem to have largely lost the plot. Please strongly consider either taking a more realistic tone, or explaining why that won't work for you?

Since you brought it up, what difference do you see between 'this is about Greek translation' and '… please Post the steps from the [Greek] source…'?

With more respect then your Posts are due, I suggest you cannot find any unbiased observer to agree I Posted anything inconsistent or unkind… though when you can, please Post the details here!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Your assertion that "sat at" is mostly irrelevant and that I could have consulted "meat" from OED to learn that in the 1600s it simply means a meal turn out to be true, which then moves the spotlight to translation issues (that I later learned from the Tour to be off-topic).  This then justifies your (maybe) trying to enlighten me to post better questions in this stack, a motivation that I well appreciate.  But in my defense, prior to posting, I wouldn't have known that the collocation "sat at" with "meat" turns out to be straightfoward; I thought there is something more to it.

Comment: Sorry… not just from 1600 but from 600 at least, if not long before. Are you not interested in the history of English?

Comment: Sorry…  Your belief that 'sat at…' matters, ruins your case. Does anyone here doubt that?

Despite your 'defense' I suggest next time, this time and every other time, you do more research.

Could that work for you?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have been around SE long enough to know the etiquette of doing research before posing the question, but at the same time I am a newbie in the history of the English language and do not have your instinct and your common sense to detect whether some collocation is significant or not, given that in the English of today there are special meanings attached to something like "sit in silence".  How would I know unless I ask?  Your admonishment is well taken, but also gives me a fresh reminder on what it's like for newbies in Christianity.SE where I would be the one guiding them.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you know a good book to introduce me to the history of English language, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150552/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-robbie-goodwin).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Jesus is having a meal.

When learning Middle English (the English that was common from about 1100-1500, just before the period we're discussing), I was taught to be skeptical of false friends, or lexemes that exist today in similar form but mean something different.

*Meat* is one of these terms. Today it means the flesh of animals people eat, and that meaning goes all the way back to Old English. But before the mid-1600s, other meanings existed too, according to the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/meat_n?tab=meaning_and_use#37488214):

- all food, sometimes as opposed to drink and sometimes a kind of drink (c1450 |     Þi **mete** schal be mylk, hony, & wiyn. in F. J. Furnivall, Political, Religious, & Love Poems (1903) 185)
- a meal (1596 | "At sitting downe and rising from **meat**, they give him thankes." Bishop W. Barlow, translation of L. Lavater, Three Christian Serm. iii. 117)

In this case, to **sit at meat** means to have a meal. See def. I.3:

> A meal, a feast. Sometimes: spec. the principal meal of a day, dinner. Also in various prepositional phrases (mostly somewhat archaic). at (†the) meat, †at meat and meal: at table, at or during a meal or meals. Similarly after meat, before meat, †to go to meat, etc. Now archaic and regional.

*To sit* is a common verb to use with being at a table, at dinner, and so on. To sit at meat would entail not necessarily a meal with meat, but at the least a major meal.

The use of this phrasing may have to do with prior English translations of Mark 2:15. For instance, *to sit at the meat* is the phrasing used in the [Wycliffite Bible (~1382) translation of Mark 2:15](https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Wycliffe/41/2):

> And it was doon, whanne he **sat at the mete** in his hous, many pupplicans and synful men saten togidere at the mete with Jhesu and hise disciplis; for there weren many that folewiden hym.

[image: Wycliffe Bible Mark 2:15]

*Source: Manchester University digital collections*

This seems to be a translation of the [Vulgate Bible's verb](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%202%3A15&version=VULGATE) *accumberet*, literally *to lie down* but with a sense meaning *to recline at table* ([Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daccumbo)), sometimes while eating. So the Wycliffite Bible (or maybe a Biblical fragment before it) set the idea in English that Jesus was dining at a meal, and that sense persisted through the King James version.

Comment: Well played. I'm adding that traditionally apple is all fruit and rose is all flowers.

Comment: That translation of the Wycliffe Bible has no thorns!

Comment: @Spencer I didn't want to introduce a thorny topic! Thank you for the facsimile inclusion. (Also, Kate, I adjusted it to *lie*.)

Comment: Fun fact, many kinds of offerings are prescribed in the Old Testament, the peace offering, the burnt offering, the wave offering, the sin offering etc. As far as I can recall, the 'meat offering' (as the KJV translates it, translated 'grain offering' in the NIV and ESV) is the only one that doesn't involve sacrificing animals.

Answer (score 0):

The basic question is really basic, why *the Greek word κατακεῖσθαι (katakeisthai) was translated* not as "reclined at table". It's quite simply a fact that “reclined” is not ever used in this way in English, and it is exceedingly likely that ESV is a corruption by dictionaries.

The essential question for the real meaning of κατακεῖσθαι is better directed at Latin.SE, but I will venture to say that existing etymologies of κατα- "down" are at best doubtful and that -σθαι as a regular ending in Septuagint Greek would leave only κε(ι), which is really not much to work with at all. Chances are it relates to the analogy which has influenced the formation of the ending in the first place.

A *get-together* if you will.

> What is the etymology and the Elizabethan English connotations of "sat at meat"? Did "meat" imply that animal flesh was eaten, implying it's a major meal or a feast?

No, not necessarily. The phrase is the same as "sit at dinner" today, given that *meat* meant "meal" in Middle English (cf. MEC [*mē̆te*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED27542/track?counter=1&search_id=51193920) 3.).

You already gave the Greek word and you must be aware that the King James' translation is but a translation of collected works. Any inference from this to the original meaning is not warranted, at all; only to the extent that *meat* shares a similarity with *meet*, and *middle*, which recalls PIE **ḱóm*- > Ancient Greek *και*, though not *-κει-* < **ḱey-* far as I can tell.

Comment: As clarified in my comments to @RobbieGoodwin, I'm not asking about the meaning of κατακεῖσθαι , nor of its etymology. This Q is squarely about the origin of "sat at meat", the connotations in 1600s, and why the KJV translators would render the meaning "recline at table" as "sat at meat" instead of other possible renditions. Therefore, your answer doesn't really answer the question; it would be great if you could address either the origin of "sat at meat" and/or possible choices for "recline at table" meaning in Elizabethan English rather than the one ultimately chosen by the KJV translators.

Comment: Why not simply accept two things?

First 'sat at (anything)…' is wholly irrelevant. Does that much work for you?

Having set that irrelevance aside, which language in which era are you asking about?